# xlwings -How to open book in a specific app

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, xlwings

I extensively use xlwings, and sometimes I am facing the problem of quitting an app using:

```
current_book.app.quit()
```

and some other Excel instances which I don't want to close also get closed.

It is really weird that the documentation does not state a way to open a book on top of a specific app in order to avoid such problems.

So first a question: When I open a new book and say I already have 3 Excel instances(different names all of them) running (not opened with xlwings), is the new book opened in a new application or on top of any of the 3 running?

Thanks.

Comment: What about the documentation here in the quickstart guide: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#scripting-automate-interact-with-excel-from-python and in the books API reference, here: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#books

Comment: When in xw.App(add_book = False) then xw.apps returns nothing hence I cannot access the app's pid.

KeyError: 'Could not find an Excel instance with this PID.'

Comment: Go with the defaults, the auto-added book will disappear as soon as you open a specific book.

Comment: Cool thanx Felix